# How do I make the card align on the same row?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to display MySQL query in each card but how do I print the cards inline? It is now printing below one another but I want them to be on the same row horizontally.

[image]

```
<?php
            $output="";

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
            {  
                $id = $row['courseID'];
                $name = $row['courseName'];
                $category = $row['category'];
                $description = $row['description'];

                $output.=
                "
                    <div class='col-sm-12'>
                        <div class='col-md-4 mb-5'>
                            <div class='card h-100'>
                                <div class='card-body'>
                                    <h4 class='card-title'>$name</h4>
                                    <p class='card-text'>$id</p>
                                    <p class='card-text'>$description</p>
                                </div>
                            <div class='card-footer'><a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>Assign</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>";    
            }
            $output .= "</div></div>"; 
            echo $output;
            ?>
```

Comment: This problem is more related to HTML and CSS than it is to PHP. Please [edit] your question to include the generated HTML code you have and the CSS code you have.

Comment: Make new div before while loop with display: flex;

Comment: Can you show some code before defining the `$output` variable because you have closed two divs after the while loop in PHP

Comment: A simple way is set the style of the main div which is storing cards html to `white-space: nowrap` and in the while loop that is making the card html, In the first <div> you can add `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!--from here-->

            
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-5 mt-5">
                <div class="card">  

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-title">
                            <h1>title</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-text">
                            <h5>body</h5>
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-0 float-end" href="" name="readmore">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!--to here-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

duplicate the code between (from here) and (to here)

here is a for loop example I used a while ago:

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php for ($i=0; $i < count($user_elements[0]) ; $i++):?>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-5 mt-5">
                    <div class="card">

                        <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php if(isset($user_elements)){echo "../private/uploads/".$thumbnail[$i];}?>">  

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card-title">
                                <h1><?php echo $user_elements[4][$i];?></h1>
                            </div>

                            <div class="card-text">
                                <h5><?php echo $user_elements[5][$i];?></h5>
                                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-0 float-end" href="readmore.php?Post=<?php echo $user_elements[0][$i];?>" name="readmore">Read more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endfor?>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just move your while into this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a parent div with container as a class add one more div to that parent div with row as a class then add your cards in that row classed div.

ex:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      //your cards div  
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet. Grid can be better with grid-gap.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-column-gap: 0.5rem;
      grid-row-gap: 0.5rem;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .grid-item {
      background-color: #999;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 30px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">6</div>
    <div class="grid-item">7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">8</div>
    <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Increase grid if you need

Comment: also grid-gap if needed !

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new div before your while loop and join the

As you can see below, you will make a new div named cards

```
<?php
        $output="<div class='cards' style='white-space:nowrap'>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
        {  
            $id = $row['courseID'];
            $name = $row['courseName'];
            $category = $row['category'];
            $description = $row['description'];

            $output.=
            "
                <div class='col-sm-12' style='display:inline-block'>
                    <div class='col-md-4 mb-5'>
                        <div class='card h-100'>
                            <div class='card-body'>
                                <h4 class='card-title'>$name</h4>
                                <p class='card-text'>$id</p>
                                <p class='card-text'>$description</p>
                            </div>
                        <div class='card-footer'><a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>Assign</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>";    
        }
        $output .= "</div></div>"; 
        echo $output;
?>
```

I hope by using this code the cards will align in same line.